# AngularJS index of issue

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find whether the provided element is present in array or not using `indexOf` function.

But, I am not able to get whether true or false based on condition.

I am given the fiddle url .

Kindly, I need some assistance.
http://jsfiddle.net/vMzSq/17/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 Hello, {{name}}!<br>
 Super? {{contains(name)}}  
 </div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Sai';
    $scope.searchNames = ['karthik','Sai']
    $scope.contains = function(searchString) {
        return searchString.indexOf(searchNames) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be `$scope.searchNames`, not just `searchNames` (it's undefined). Also, you need to do `array.indexOf(element)`, not `element.indexOf(array)`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Sai';
  $scope.searchNames = ['karthik','Sai']
  $scope.contains = function(searchString) {
      return $scope.searchNames.indexOf(searchString) != -1;
      //  HERE ^^^
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vMzSq/23/

Or, if you don't need it in the scope, you can remove it, but be consistent:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Sai';
  var searchNames = ['karthik','Sai']
  $scope.contains = function(searchString) {
      return searchNames.indexOf(searchString) != -1;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vMzSq/22/